# Forcefully disable IE9 download manager

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer-9

I'm having some issues with a barcode scanner I'm using in a web application calld Aura, specifically designed for school libraries.

Every time a barcode is scanned IE9 will open it's download manager after which the user has to close it manually, which is completely unnecessary. 
In other browsers (Firefox, Google Chrome) this happens as well, but with their download manager.

IE9 is used most frequently at the company I work at (sad enough :/), so this browser is the only one that has priority when it comes to fixing this issue.

So in short, **is there a way to prevent IE9's download manager from popping up?**

Thanks!

Comment: Just to be explicit - rolling back to IE8 isn't an option?

Comment: Do you know why IE is trying to download a file when you scan?

Comment: We see it as our last resort, if there aren't any other ways to fix or work around this issue.

Comment: @uSlackr, no I'm not sure, I was expecting it to handle the barcode scanner like any other input device, in the end, all information send by the scanner is a string of symbols.

Comment: I think you might want to focus on what about the data makes IE want to download something rather then break the download manager.  As soon as you do, the user will need to download something.  IMO, you aren't chasing the right issue yet.

Comment: @uSlackr I completely agree with you, however, as this a third party application I have no control over it's source code. Been looking into the drivers of the scanner too, but can't seem to find any things to tweak or any drivers to install.

Comment: If the site is on restricted , it might stop any download from being initiated, but that might also mean that standard scripts do not run.  Worth a try, be surprised how functional most sites are even when they are on restricted.  When all else fails you can try and weed through source code, but it would help if you knew what the "item" is or at least extention of it.  I have seen that rarely occur with some special item, that it seems to choose to put on a download list, as opposed to "activate" it on the page?  I donno, but usually it is unnessisary. Best resource would be the makers.